Static typing python problem(ide does not see the class?)
I write in VS Code and it seems like the IDE does not see the custom class. May I ask for any sugestions why?
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.x},{self.y}")
    def move(self,vx,vy):
        self.x+=vx
        self.y+=vy
            
    def calc_dist(self,point2:Point):
        print(((self.x-point2.x)**2+(self.y-point2.y)**2)**0.5)


p1=Point(3,4)
p2=Point(2,5)

p1.calc_dist(p2)

I have tried do add __string__ method and change the name of the second argument/class name but it didn't helped.

Duplicate: How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?.

__string__ is not a standard dunder method, it's __str__.

Is this only a problem in VS Code? Does it work as expected with mypy?

What does "does not see" even mean? If you're going to tag this as "python" instead of "vs-code", describe the specific error or warning in enough detail that people who don't use Microsoft tools can understand it.

@Barmar yes, i tried __str__ not __string__.
A great thanks to @InSync. The 'Point' did the job !!!
